# Informatica - copy XML views from source qual. to xml parser transformation

Tags: xml, informatica

Informatica. I would like to be able to copy my XML Views from my source qualifier to an XML Parser Transformation. We have around 75 custom views and really do not want to spend days having to redo these if at all possible. Any help would be appreciated.[Sample of XML Views in Source Qualifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWKvh.jpg)

Comment: Can you put some more description on what you need to do? Or perhaps share some image? I don't know what you mean by "copy my XML Views from my source qualifier to an XML Parser ".

Comment: When we import the XML document, we are given option to generate views. In a few instances we have had the need to not allow Informatica to generate the views but to create them manually. Currently, we have around 75 views for one XML document which would be very time consuming to recreate if we switch over to using an XML Parser Transformation instead of the Source Qualifier. I also attached an image of View screen to the original question. Hope this helps!

Comment: Check this out: http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2013/03/adding-port-to-existing-xml-parser.html

Comment: It's about modifying the XML-based mappings without a need for re-creating the XML Parser and loosing the connections. Hope it helps.

Comment: Maciejg, when you imported your saved file into the XML Parser Transformation ---- did the wizard pop up asking how you would like the xml views to be generated? If so, what option did you pick to retain your custom views?

Comment: Yes, it pops up. I can choose to use Entity Relationships, Hierarchy, Custom, use XML Definition or not create at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it. Edit the source and choose `View XML Metadata as XML/DTD/Schema` icon (or `View` => `XML Metadata`). Generate a file that will store all the cutom XML Views you've created. 
Now, go to the mapping and create the `XML Parser Transformation`. In the `Import XML Definition` dialog choose the created file. It should read and create all your views.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I do believe you understand my issue perfectly. Unfortunately, I saved my views as  a.dtd and a .xml file and when I use them to create the XML parser ---Informatica is creating its own relationships and views. I have tried every option available on the import and nothing recreates the custom views saved from the SQ. It would be nice if I could create the parser with no views as I did in SQ and then import the saved views but that does not seem to be an option.

Comment: I tried my best, not sure why it's not working :( It seemed to do the trick - after I've created the XML Parser in the mapping using the created file, it seemed fine. I'm not sure I understand the "Informatica is creating its own relationships and views" part, however.